# CSS and jQuery menu cuts off due small page size

Tags: jquery, css, menu, cross-browser

My problem is that my menu which is designed using css and jQuery is having some problems. Whenever I hover on the menu a long sublist drops down, it is ok for the bigger page size but it gets cut off whenever displayed on a small page.

Comment: need more info... sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Solution For Very Long Dropdown Menus](http://css-tricks.com/long-dropdowns-solution/)

Comment: Hey Sarfraz the solution you gave is quite cool but, I'm not much familiar to J-query and it is becoming very tough for me to modify my menu's code.

Comment: well now there are two things: either you learn jquery which you will need most likely at some stage or use the solution i posted and modify the css of it if you can.